# Set up of home mail server

Tags: email, dynamic-ip

I would like to ask is having a mail server at home using dynamic IP is possible. I am in need of a mail server to send emails out to all my customers which my share hosting service provider has stop me due to the larger quantity at any one time.

I am force to look for alternative like having my own server at home to hold a new domain and just to do the sending. If having a static IP, I know it is possible, but the cost of having a static IP is far out of my reach. That's why wanted to see if dynamic IP is possible I am not sure if it can be done. Can any one please guide me? thanks

Comment: good question +1!

Comment: Investigate alternative ISPs, I used to work for one that gave out static IPs to residential users for $10/month.

Answer (score 2):

Well, most mail servers these days block dynamic IP addresses due to spam. You can set one up but chances are it will not work.

If its for a small number of accounts, you could probably give [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) a shot, you can set it up with your domain and use it with good old fashioned IMAP

Comment: no worries, i was meaning to look up the url, but got sidetracked - though for less than 10 addresses the 'normal' google apps (not the business varient) might do http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Journeyman Geek the mail server at home will not work - your IP range will be 'wrong'.

I suspect that you are not sending out your newsletter/emails the right way. If you put a newsletter mailer program on your server then you can s-l-o-w-l-y send emails out. This will keep your ISP happy. Investigate phplist - it is used by Greenpeace and it will also enable your customers to opt out of mailings. Because it is open Source you can edit the code and put any customer-specific, tailored content that you need to.